# Does Azure front door actively replicate its cache?

Tags: azure-front-door

Does the AFD cache push / replicate out to additional POP's, once an initial request to a single POP has completed? I cant find any documentation on the AFD documentation in relation to this.

Ultimately what I want to know is:

If an initial request occurs from EU, served by the EU POP (after pull though from origin server); then 1h later an identical request occurs from the US, is this request a 'cache hit' in the US POP, or a miss with a read through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first request by the any POP will not be cached. As per your example, the request sent form US will be a MISS and any subsequent request will be cached in that POP server.

Comment: This is mostly correct (and enough to answer the question). See my follow on answer below, which contains detail our account rep sent on.

Answer (score 1):

We were seeing mixed behaviour on our systems, and the below extract explains how AFD functions, and why we got the mixed behaviour.

> Lets say out of out of 100 POPs globally, we have 20 super POPs. The remaining 80 will
>   never reach the API backend directly but will only go to super POPs.
>   And then the Super POPs go to your API to pull the content. There on
>   not just the initial POP but also the super POP now have the cached
>   content. Across the globe the Super POPs keep getting warmed up with
>   the cache content.    Each Edge POP has a mapping to a Super POP. This
>   overall helps improve cache hit ration significantly and also
>   significantly reduces the load on your application backends.